# SqlConnection error in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using C# and a SQL Server database. I have set up the server to Windows and SQL Server authentication.

When I try to connect to the database from my computer, everything works fine, but when I'm trying to connect from a different computer (on the same network) with the same connection string I get:

> Error: 26 - unable to locate server.

**Note**: I tried to log in via SQL Server authentication, and not Windows auth.

Inside the SQL Server, I made sure remote connection option is available. I have also enabled the port in the firewall.

This is my connection string:

```
Server=MY-PC\\MSSQLSERVER1;User ID=loginuser;Password=p@ssword;DataBase=DB;
```

Comment: What is the error message received? Did you try to search about this error with your preferite search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect this server from the other computer by SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

If there is connection problem it means that ports are not available or firewall works.

In addition, SQL Server Browser may not work.

If you can connect by SSMS, then check the your local server connection parameters or connection access control.

Because of the user authentication probelm, you cannot connect the server.

If you have your error message, I can help in detail.

Answer (score 0):

On PC-2 I would verify that you have the correct ports open on the firewall (1433 by default).

To test your connection string:

1. On the desktop right click and create a new blank text file called test.txt.
2. Rename it text.udl.
3. Double click it and you will now be able to enter in your info for the connection string and test it.
4. Make sure you start on the Provider tab and select the Provider for SQL Server.
5. When you have one that works, close the file and then reopen it in notepad and you can cut and paste the connection string right from there.

I would also try and use the IP address instead of the server name to make sure you rule out any DNS issues on your network.